# Include disqus.html only if post.category == 'textual' not working

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, liquid

Using **Jekyll**, I'm trying to **only include** the disqus.html in posts with the 'textual' category:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Menú lateral -->
    {%include menu-lateral.html%}
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="main-content-post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
          {{content}}

          {% if post.category == "textual" %}
            {% include disqus.html %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though, it doesn't works :~)

Comment: Try to render `post.category` maybe it's capitalised or smth. Have you checked that condition is correct?

Comment: @zishe Yeah, it is correct, and there's any other text format.

Comment: I solved it changing post.category for page.category.

Comment: @dawn It would be better if you could write up how you solved your problem as an answer, so that it's more obvious to someone else who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing `post.category` for `page.category`.